# Is there a way to provide access privileges to USB scanner via TWAIN SANE-backends for all users in Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)?

Tags: macos, permissions, scanner

I want to enable all users of a Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) system to use a USB flatbed scanner. Such scanner works using [TWAIN SANE](http://www.ellert.se/twain-sane/) from my account (admin) without `sudo`-ing, while other users can run `xsane` but cannot see the device in any way. These are the groups I am member of:

> staff everyone localaccounts _appserverusr admin _appserveradm
>   _lpadmin com.apple.sharepoint.group.1 com.apple.sharepoint.group.2 com.apple.sharepoint.group.3 _appstore _lpoperator _developer
>   com.apple.access_screensharing com.apple.access_ssh

Other users are members of the following groups:

> staff com.apple.sharepoint.group.2 everyone localaccounts
>   com.apple.sharepoint.group.3 _lpoperator com.apple.sharepoint.group.1

Is there any way to solve the issue adding other users to one of my extra groups? Anyway, I would prefer to respect the principle of least privilege and provide guests only access to the specific resource.